# Effect of Thread.sleep on a runnable task waiting on windows to complete file creation/moving

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, daemon, thread-sleep

I have a condition where file moving/creation on windows folder is creating a timing problem for a task to proceed using file on that path

So I am sleeping the deamon thread running that task using thread.sleep(30ms) until windows does it work and allows my task to run fine without any FileNotFoundException.

Initialization Class

```
 Thread t = new Thread (processTask);
 t.setdaemon(true)
 t.start();
```

Task class

```
 class ProcessTask() extends Runnable 
  {
   Files.move(source, destination, copyoption);
   Thread.sleep(30ms); //to wait for windows to complete move
   new FileInputstream(sourceFile);
  }
```

**Would thread.sleep(30ms) for sure sleep only my current deamon thread** ? Would there be a way to confirm where sleep is acting

Comment: Your code is contradicting. If you move from `source` to `destination`, it should be obvious that you can’t open the source afterwards, though, granted, `sourceFile` is a variable not involved in the operation at all. Besides, `FileInputstream` uses different library code than NIO. Assuming that `destination` is a `Path` representing what you actually want to open, I’d try `Files.newInputStream(destination)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` affects the current thread. It doesn't put other threads to sleep.

However using `Thread.sleep()` is never a good idea to use for program logic. Especially when waiting for some other action to finish. Those should be handled with notification mechanisms, not waiting random amounts and hope that everything will work.